# Why does my code not put out the right answer when I use the if statement?

Tags: java

This is the class that contains main.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        Random r = new Random();
        int number = 1 + r.nextInt(3);

        System.out.println(number);

        if (number == 1) {
            name = "Kobe";
        }
        else if (number == 2) {
            name = "Mamba";
        }
        else {
            name = "lol";
        }

        RandomTest2 object = new RandomTest2(name);
        System.out.println(object.toString());
    }
}
```

This class contains other methods.

```
public class RandomTest2 {

    private String name;

    public RandomTest2(String name) {
        name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

If I remove the If statement and I assign a value directly to name, it works..

I just want to randomly assign properties to the object.

Answer (score 3):

You just missed a `this` in your constructor:

```
public RandomTest2(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Without it, you are just assigning the `name` parameter to itself.

No worries, this gets every Java coder at least once ;-)

Comment: Nope, it never got me.  (Then again, I had been programming 35 years and worked on maintaining a compiler before I learned Java, so it would have been obvious to me that this couldn't have worked.)

Comment: @ajb bravoooooo

Answer (score 2):

Instead of name = name as shown below

```
RandomTest2(String name) {
    name = name;
}
```

Try

```
this.name=name;
```

Answer (score 1):

on this function:

```
public RandomTest2(String name) {
    name = name;
}
```

the compiler is understand that you assign name to itself not for the name variable on RandomTest2. So change it to `this.name = name.`

Answer (score 0):

class RandomTest2 -> constructor method -> this.name = name